# How to check instanceof parent class?

Tags: php, instanceof

In PHP there is two classes:
`class parentTroll {...}` and `class troll extends parentTroll {...}`

And then there is an object `$troll = new troll();`

How to check `$troll instanceof parentTroll`? This line returns false now.

Answer (score 18):

Following example returns true:

```
class parentTroll {}
class troll extends parentTroll {}
$troll = new troll();

var_dump($troll instanceof parentTroll);
```

Output:

```
boolean true
```

You can also use `ReflectionClass`:

```
var_dump((new ReflectionClass($troll))->getParentClass()->getName() == 'parentTroll');
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation disagrees

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php

And so does my testing of your code.

Comment: Could you explain how it disagrees. It looks like it works with parent classes in Example #2: "Using instanceof with inherited classes"

Comment: "This line returns false now" is what I was disagreeing with. It actually returns true (as the accepted answer also says).

Answer (score 0):

There is metho is_subclass_of. Just use is_subclass_of($troll, Parent::class)